# Data driven in Karate with multiple columns along with karate.setup() is Possible?

Tags: api, karate, dsl, automation-testing

Can I validate multiple values in the response when use path from each element in array while I am using @setup in Karate framework. In example I can pass as many as columns and validate them with response.

Please refer the following snippet for more details

`Feature:

@setup
Scenario:
* def data = [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2322 }, { id: 33 } ]

Scenario Outline:
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* path id
* method get

```
Examples:
  |id                   |StatusCode|ResponseMessage| 
  | karate.setup().data |200       |Ok             |`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all JSON keys in the `data` will be converted into "columns", here is an example, try it:

```
Feature:

@setup
Scenario:
* def data = [{ id: 1, code: 200}, { id: 2, code: 200}]

Scenario Outline: id: ${id}
* url `https://httpbin.org/anything/${id}`
* method get
* match responseStatus == code

Examples:
| karate.setup().data |
```

Karate supports the built-in variable `responseStatus`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#responsestatus

Response Message is typically never needed.